# How to divide or separate boxplots in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I have more than 100 boxplots in one graph, which is hard to read. I want to divide it into 3 to 5 graphs, so it will be easy for people to see each boxplot.

```
boxplot(Flanker$TrialSlide_RT ~ Flanker$Subject, main="Boxplot", ylab="Reaction time", xlab="Number of participants", ylim=c(0,1000), las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a self contained minimal reproducible example.  No one can run your code.  See [mcve] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subset your original dataframe then you can plot each of them separately.

Lets say you split it every 20th rows.
You can plot it using:

```
boxplot(DF[1:20,1]~DF[1:20,2],main="Boxplot 1", ylab="Reaction time", 
xlab="Number of participants", ylim=c(0,1000), las=1)
```

Where your dataframe is `"DF"` and by using `DF[1:20,1]` you're subsetting the first 20th rows of your dataframe and selecting the first column to plot agains the second column of the first 20th rows (`DF[1:20,2]`).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't this potentially break up any repetition by `Subject`? Surely you'd want to select the first `n` `Subject`s.

Comment: I just want to divide those boxplots into different graphs.

boxplot(Flanker[1:4800,20]~Flanker[1:4800,1],main="Boxplot 1", ylab="Number of participants", 
        xlab="Reaction time", ylim=c(0,1000), las=1, horizontal=TRUE)

boxplot(Flanker[4801:9600,20]~Flanker[4801:9600,1],main="Boxplot 2", ylab="Number of participants", 
        xlab="Reaction time", ylim=c(0,1000), las=1, horizontal=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Break up the data (`Flanker$Subject` in your case) into meaningful groups and plot them separately. Alternatively, consider using `ggplot2` and its `facet_wrap()` options to do this automatically.

Comment: can you tell me more about it because I don't know how to use it to divide the data.

Comment: I can't do much specific without access to your data, but decide on some grouping variable to split up your data (either a natural one or make one using something like `cut`) and specify that in the plot construction. Here's a brief intro to facetting in ggplot2: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/